# set the null value column to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a temp table from the actual table. Now in the actual table for the column Rewrite_Count its showing nulls. I need those nulls to be replaced with 0. Can someone help me on getting the correct code.

```
SELECT *
INTO policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap_20190403
FROM Policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap;
```

Comment: 1) You are not creating a temp table. 2) Use `ISNULL(Column, 0)` in your `SELECT`

Comment: Hi Sam, Yea I am not creating sorry I am Selecting the Snapshot table data into a table 20190403.

Comment: Is every column that contains a NULL a numeric datatype? It would help if you shared some details of the table and the data.

Comment: What's wrong with null? 0 doesn't mean the same...

Comment: @jarlh "What's wrong with null?" -- Philosophically... well, a ton of things :D For starters no one know what it means. Just kidding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISNULL()`

```
SELECT ISNULL(Rewrite_Count, 0) Rewrite_Count, --Other columns
INTO policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap_20190403
FROM Policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap;
```

Comment: Tip: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100715082018/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can basically update the value of the column:

```
update policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap_20190403
set Rewrite_Count  = 0
where Rewrite_Count is null
```

The solution above assumes Rewrite_Count column is type of integer.

Comment: This just updates the snap_20190403. I need the ISNULL = 0 logic for the Monthly_Policy_snap table.

Comment: @Sam what do you mean that you need isnull=0 logic? Do you want t eliminate the data where Rewrite_Count is null at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
update policy.Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap_20190403
set Rewrite_Count  = IsNull(Rewrite_Count,0)
where Rewrite_Count is null
```

Comment: Since you include `Rewrite_Count IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause, why `ISNULL()` needed?

Comment: Not sure he wants to update the data, but maybe he just wants to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Default` to the `Rewrite_Count` field on `Monthly_Policy_Snap`.  That way, if someone adds a record to the table and doesn't specify a value for `Monthly_Policy_Snap`, the system will set it to 0.

You can add that with `Alter Table ... Alter Column`

Read more about the `Default` constraint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1):

Note Select into statement copies only some properties like   column name,data type but most important it doest not include constraint,trigger etc.

You can use coalesce and isnull for replacing with 0. Coalesce is standard and isnull is tsql specific. If source column is of not null then both coalesce and isnull will set the property of resulted column to not null . But if source column is null then isnull will set the resulted column to not null.